# How to delete lines that match elements from another file

Tags: linux, perl, centos, protein-database

I am in the process of learning Perl and I am trying to figure out how to do this task. I have a folder with a bunch of text files and I have a file `ions_solvents_cofactors` that contains bunch of three letters list.

I wrote a script that opens and reads each file in a folder and should delete those lines that under a specific column [3] matches with some element from the list. It is not working well. I have some problem at the end of the script and cant figure out what it is.

Error I get is : `rm: invalid option -- '5'`

My input file look like this:

```
ATOM   1592 HD13 LEU D  46      11.698 -10.914   2.183  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   1593 HD21 LEU D  46      11.528  -8.800   5.301  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   1594 HD22 LEU D  46      12.997  -9.452   4.535  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   1595 HD23 LEU D  46      11.722  -8.718   3.534  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM 1597  N1  308 A   1       0.339   6.314  -9.091  1.00  0.00           N  
HETATM 1598  C10 308 A   1      -0.195   5.226  -8.241  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 1599  C7  308 A   1      -0.991   4.254  -9.133  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 1600  C1  308 A   1      -1.468   3.053  -8.292  1.00  0.00           C
```

Here is the script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$dirname = '.';
opendir( DIR, $dirname ) or die "cannot open directory";
@files = grep( /\.txt$/, readdir( DIR ) );

foreach $files ( @files ) {

    open( FH, $files ) or die "could not open $files\n";
    @file_each = <FH>;
    close FH;

    close DIR;

    my @ion_names = ();

    my $ionfile   = 'ions_solvents_cofactors';
    open( ION, $ionfile ) or die "Could not open $ionfile, $!";
    my @ion = <ION>;
    close ION;

    for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#file_each; $line++ ) {

        chomp( $file_each[$line] );
        if ( $file_each[$line] =~ /^HETATM/ ) {
            @is = split '\s+', $file_each[$line];
            chomp $is[3];
        }

        foreach ( $file_each[$line] ) {    #line 39

            if ( "@ion" =~ $is[3] ) {
                system( "rm $file_each[$line]" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for example if `308` from the input file matches in the file ions_cofactors_solvents` then delete all these lines in which it matches.

Comment: It would help you a lot if you laid out your program properly, and it is only polite to do so when you are asking for free help with your code. Please fix it: it is virtually unreadable as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. I am not using any text editor which is bad. I have change it

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to improve layout. It has however made things worse, at least by removing the essential identification of line 39.

Comment: If you continue editing, please: 1) indent by at most 4 chars 2) use spaces, not tabs (or at least use either consistently) 3) not more than one empty line at once, and then only with good reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to make it easier to read by putting more spaces and tabs, thats all.

Comment: Could you double check that the code as shown now (after many edits) is still the code which causes the error you describe?

Comment: It doesnt give me the same error, it gives me now this warning: `Global symbol "$files" requires explicit package name at select_pdb_filesREAL.pl line 11.` Although after running the script it didnt make any changes and deleted any lines in the files.

Comment: Please explain your understanding of line 39 `foreach($file_each[$line])`. What is the list to process? What is the variable to take each list entry? How many entries are in the list?

Comment: You edited `use stricts;` into the code. You now have to work with that. You should keep it, fix the errors it causes (e.g. by adding a few strategic `my`s) and then come back with the sanitised code which gives you the initial error again. Or maybe trying that fixes it. Then please make an answer yourself or keep the question deleted.

Comment: With your last comment, your question is now prone to get some close-votes for "not reproducable error", maybe downvotes. So better delete the question now, debug, test, edit and then undelete.

Comment: I splitted each line that starts with `^HETATM` and took only fourth element `is[3]`, but I didn't pushed these elements into an array. I wanted to say that foreach line that starts with `^HETATM` see if the elements `is[3]` in each line match with the one that are in the `@ion` array and for those who are delete whole lines from the input files. I also tried to push all `is[3]` from each line into and array and then to use this array into foreach loop, but I had the same problem.

Comment: Ok, Ill do so..

Comment: You can't remove lines from a file using `rm`! Please give an example of the contents of `ions_solvents_cofactors`.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to declare every variable globally at the top of the program. The declaration should be as close as possible to the first occurrence of the variable.

Comment: Do you want to delete the lines from the original PDB files, or do you want to keep a backup copy?

Comment: I tought that if using `system` command or `` I can do it same way as a bash command. But I am probably wrong. Content of  `ions_solvents_cofactors` is a list of different letters that look like this: `SB
SN
IN
008
03S
06C
0KA
0NG
0NM` So if `308` is found under this list I wanted to remove all these lines in which 308 is found in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the variable declaration, I am not that experienced so this is very useful. These are txt files, and it does not matter, I can overwrite over original txt file or make and copy new one into different folder.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using centos 6.9

Comment: @milan: Your PDB file doesn't follow the [*Protein Data Bank* format](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM) so my solutions just splits each line on whitespace. I assume you want to match the ***Atom name*** field?

Comment: @milan: With the possibility of off-by-one errors, I assume that you're referring to the column that contains `LEU` and `308` in your sample?

Comment: @milan: You almost *never* want `split /\s+/`, and if you're *sure* that you do you should add a comment to your code to explain yourself. `split ' '` is probably correct. It is also the default, so if you leave the file record in `$_` you can say just `my @fields = split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make use of the
[`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File)
module, which allows you to `tie` an array to the module so that any changes you make to the array are reflected in the file

I've used `glob` to find all the `.txt` files, with the option `:bsd_glob` so as to support spaces in the file paths

The first job is to build a hash `%matches` that maps all the values in `ions_solvents_cofactors` to 1. This makes it trivial to test the PDB files for the required values

Then it's just a matter of using `tie` on each `.txt` file, and testing each line to see whether the value in column 4 is represented in the hash

I use variable `$i` to index into the `@file` array which maps the on-disk file. If a match is found then the array element is deleted with `splice @file, $i, 1`. (This naturally leaves `$i` indexing the next element in sequence without incrementing `$i`.) If there is no match then `$i` is incremented to index the next array element, leaving the line in place

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';
use Tie::File;

my %matches = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'ions_solvents_cofactors.txt';
    local $/;
    map { $_ => 1 } split ' ', <$fh>;
};

for my $pdb ( glob '*.txt' ) {

    tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $pdb or die $!;

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @file; ) {

        next unless my $col4 = ( split ' ', $file[$i] )[3];

        if ( $matches{$col4} ) {
            printf qq{Removing line %d from "%s"\n},
                    $i+1,
                    $pdb;
            splice @file, $i, 1;
        }
        else {
            ++$i;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have never used any module, I guess that if they are not built that I can easily install them. Thank You for Your explanation. This look like a super organised code, with Your description I understood it well. I will run it tomorrow morning cause I am on the far east, time to sleep. I hope it removes whole lines whenever col4 matches element from the file. Just wanted to ask You, in my previous code, I know that the level of skills in low, but how could have I changed this remove line in perl so that it works as well? Just to know in the future if I encounter with the same kind of task.

Comment: @milan: `Tie::File` was added to core Perl with version 5.7.3 in March 2002. If your perl is older than that then you really should consider updating it, otherwise my code should work as it stands. There are many useful modules available with standard Perl, but one of the biggest advantages of Perl is the [*Comprehensive Perl Archive Network* (CPAN)](https://www.cpan.org/) where ordinary people like you and I may submit code that could be useful to others. Standard command-line tools like sed and awk become irrelevant if you know perl.

Comment: @milan: *"I hope it removes whole lines whenever col4 matches element from the file"* As I said, [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File)
maps each line of a text file to an array element. If you read the documentation on [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) then you will see that it removes elements from an array. That means it will also delete a line from the PDB file. But you *must always* let the program run to completion. If you interrupt it then the file will probably be unusable.

Comment: `"bsd_glob" is not defined in %File::Glob::EXPORT_TAGS at script_coord.pl line 5
 main::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 5
 eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 5
Can't continue after import errors at script_coord.pl line 5` This is the error I got when I try to run the script. I have searched on the internet how to define bsd_glob in Centos but couldn't find it. I am using perl 5.10 so I guess that this is not a problem

Comment: I have tried to run it by deleting `bsd_glob`, its running but it still removing some lines that under 4th column doesn't have element matching `elements from ion_solvent_cofactor` file. However it has to search only col4 of those lines that start with `^HETATM`. So, I ran it on some .txt that don't have `^HETATM` and it was stillremoving some lines. It also removes lines when I ran it on the files that under `^HETATM` 4th column doesn't have elements that matches with one from the list. For example on one file, it needs to remove only 4 lines, and it removes around 3000 lines which is strange

Comment: @milan: There is no mention of any of this in your question. Reduce your problem to a small sample of data that we can work with and ask a new question, showing both your PDB file and the list file. And you should have `:bsd_glob`, not `bsd_glob`.

Comment: Yeah, You are right! I completely lost to mention it into the question. Sorry for that. I will open a new question and make it clear what is the problem if it is not working with the script that You have wrote. Anyway, if it also reads lines that start with `^ATOM` is shouldnt be a problem because under `col[4]` of `^ATOM` there shouldn't be any element that matches with the content of `ions_solvents_cofactors` file

Comment: @milan: If you add a list file to this question that doesn't give the correct results with the PDB that you have already shown then we may be able to avoid a whole new question. The problem is undoubtedly that you haven't fully specified the requirement.