# How to delete lines that in specific column match elements from another file

Tags: perl

I have a folder with many text files that look like this:

```
ATOM   5132 HG22   ILE   B 162     -10.906  60.208   9.028  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   5133 HG23   ILE   B 162     -11.193  58.585   9.650  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   5134 HD11   ILE   B 162      -9.888  57.413   9.161  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   5135 HD12   ILE   B 162      -8.448  57.195   8.181  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM   5136 HD13   ILE   B 162      -9.913  56.300   7.799  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM 5138 ZN    ZN A 190      30.757  32.494  -1.721  1.00  0.00          ZN  
HETATM 5139  C1  UQ1 B 501       2.889  33.364  18.810  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 5140  O1  UQ1 B 501       2.849  32.140  19.037  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM 5141  C2  UQ1 B 501       4.162  33.930  18.303  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 5142  O2  UQ1 B 501       5.209  33.069  18.099  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM 5143  CM2 UQ1 B 501       5.802  32.349  19.180  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 5144  C3  UQ1 B 501       4.270  35.396  18.017  1.00  0.00           C
```

I have a file `ions_solvents_cofactors` that contains different number of symbols, and look like this:

```
ZN
008
03S
06C
0KA
0NG
0NM
0QE
144
1CL
1SA
1TP
202
21H
2A6
2BM
2F2
2HE
2HP
2MO
2NO
2PA
2PN
2PO
2T8
```

I wrote a program that 
should open and read each `.txt` file in the current folder and delete those lines where column 4 matches with any value from the file `ions_solevnts_cofactors` when column 1 is `HETATM`.

It gives me this error

```
rm: cannot remove `ATOM': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `1459': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `HB': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `ILE': No such file or directory
```

This is the script

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$dirname = '.';
opendir( DIR, $dirname ) or die "cannot open directory";
@files = grep( /\.txt$/, readdir( DIR ) );

foreach $files ( @files ) {

    open( FH, $files ) or die "could not open $files\n";
    @file_each = <FH>;
    close FH;

    close DIR;

    my @ion = ();

    my $ionfile = 'ions_solvents_cofactors';

    open( ION, $ionfile ) or die "Could not open $ionfile, $!";
    my @ion = <ION>;
    close ION;

    for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#file_each; $line++ ) {

        chomp( $file_each[$line] );

        if ( $file_each[$line] =~ /^HETATM/ ) {
            @is = split '\s+', $file_each[$line];
            chomp $is[3];
        }

        foreach ( $file_each[$line] ) {    # line 39

            if ( "@ion" =~ $is[3] ) {
                system( "rm $file_each[$line]" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the script to overwrite each text file and reads only the fourth column of the lines that starts with `HETATM`. If it matches any of the elements from file `ions_solvents_cofactors` then this line should be deleted.

So, for example

```
HETATM 5138 ZN    ZN A 190      30.757  32.494  -1.721  1.00  0.00          ZN
```

this line should be deleted from the file because `ZN` matches.

Comment: You're lying to us, and that isn't a good look. You were told in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166370/how-to-delete-lines-that-match-elements-from-another-file) to add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the beginning. You have added those lines to the top of this question only to avoid the same  scolding, but you have never run your program that way. The code you show doesn't even compile: it produces twenty lines of errors starting with `"my" variable @ion masks earlier declaration in same scope` because you have declared `@ion` twice.

Comment: I understand that you may be unfamiliar with Perl, but that lack of knowledge doesn't explain you posting code that you haven't tried to run. Together with the appearance that, instead of copying and pasting any solutions here you're trying to copy-type them in, so as to mistake `:bsd_glob` for `bsd_glob` *twice* from *two different answers*, it is pretty much impossible to know how to advise you. If we can't trust anything that you write then we have absolutely no basis to diagnose your problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of needed improvements, and a few direct errors.

First a simple working code, with some assumptions taken from the question

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

#use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';   # using \Q..\E in glob, no need for this
use File::Copy qw(move);
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);

my $dirname = shift @ARGV || '.';

my $ionfile = 'ions_solvents_cofactors';
open my $fh, '<', $ionfile or die "Can't open $ionfile: $!";
my @ion_terms = <$fh>;
chomp @ion_terms;

my @files = glob "\Q$dirname\E/*.txt";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or do {
       warn "Can't open $file: $!";
       next;
    };
    my $outfile = $file . '_new';
    open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

    while (<$fh>) {
        next if not /^HETATM/;
        my @fields = split;
        next if any { $fields[3] =~ /$_/ } @ion_terms;
        print $fh_out $_; 
    }   

    # Uncomment to overwrite, when thoroughly tested
    #move $outfile, $file or warn "Can't move $outfile to $file: $!"
}
```

Comments

- The reference file need be opened only once; get it out of the loop
- No purpose in "initializing" an array to emtpy, like `my @ion = ()`. You get that when you declare it with `my @ion`. (If you need to clear an array, then `@ary = ();` makes sense)
- Use lexical filehandles, `open my $fh, ...`, instead of typeglobs `FH`. Use lexical filehandles. Use lexical filehandles. See end of [Typeglobs and Filehandles](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) and read [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- There is practically never a need for a C-style `foreach` loop. If you need to iterate over index, `for my $i (0..$#ary)` is great. But most of the time you need *elements*, like here
- Instead of the `\s+` pattern used in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) you should use `' '`, which is also `split`'s default. This is why the code above doesn't need it, as `split;` is the same as `split ' ', $_;`
- The `@file_each` is not a good name for lines in the file
- Direct error: you are attempting to `rm` what is a *line* in a file! Better naming would've helped
- Your use of `opendir` and `readdir` is fine (except for `DIR` instead of a lexical filehandle!!), but `glob` is better here.   **Edit:**   I use [`\Q..\E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters) in `glob`, to prevent possible injection bug whereby an unusual directory name triggers unintended processing. Since those also escape spaces the [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) with its `bsd_glob()` isn't needed any more
- I use [List::MoreUtils::any](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.428/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#any_BLOCK_LIST) to find whether any element from `@ion_terms` satisfies the condition in the block, to match `$fields[3]`. This can be done with `grep` as well.  Also, if your list of terms is as short as shown, you can assemble a regex pattern with it

  ```
  my $re = join '|', { quotemeta } @ion_terms;  # before the loop
  next if $fields[3] =~ /$re/;
  ```
- Some of the code above can be written more concisely and simply

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I get this error `Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC ` which probably means that I have to install this module. I have just to check it is it possible on Centos 6.9. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have installed this module and now when I run the script id does not gives me any error, it doesn creates new `txt.new` files but they are empty?

Comment: @milan I tested with files derived from the one you show, and with the reference file that you show.  It puts the new files in the same directory where the files are (but you can set names as you wish).

Comment: @ zdim: Thanks..very strange. When I create a new file with the same content that I put above and run the script it also gives me blank txt.new. Have to check why is this happening when I run it.

Comment: @milan This is how I test. I make a directory and put a file like the one you show there (and make up another, similar one). Then I put `ions_..` reference file in the directory with the script.  (I actually enter the name of the directory where the file is in the code instead of `'.'` but you can also give its name when you run the script.) So the file is in `test_dir/`, the reference file is where the script is, and then run `script test_dir`. That's it. I re-tested afresh.

Comment: Haha maan..I did the same and now I run it again and it gives me this error :P `"bsd_glob" is not defined in %File::Glob::EXPORT_TAGS at removing_lines.pl line 5
 main::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 5
 eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 5
Can't continue after import errors at removing_lines.pl line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at removing_lines.pl line 5.` I will install it now as well. Sorry to bother You and thank You!

Comment: @milan Huh?  `File::Glob` is core.  Btw, you can just drop that, just remove `use File::Glob`.  The effect of that is to replace the basic [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) with the BSD one, but the basic `glob` will work fine if your files don't have spaces in their names.

Comment: Hm, yes..I did it and it still prints blank page. I went trought the script and it seems to be fine. Maybe something is wrong with my computer or tiredness, Ill try it on other operative system or later on the same and Ill came back to You tomorrow. Anyway, thank You for this, You helped me alot!

Comment: `next if not /^HETATM/` will remove all non-`HETATM` from the output; I think they're supposed to remain in place. And `next if any { $fields[3] =~ /$_/ } @ion_terms` will match if an element of `@ion_terms` is a *substring* of the data field; I think you want just `eq`.

Comment: *"I use `File::Glob` since its glob handles spaces in filenames"* Yes, but only if you enable the `:bsd_glob` option

Comment: @milan: This is the same mistake you made with your previous question. There is a *colon* before `bsd_glob`. You need `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'` as zdim shows in his solution. You must *copy and paste* code from the internet to your editor. If you try to type it in there may be any number of errors that we don't know about and so can't help you with.

Comment: @Borodin As for `File::Glob` -- indeed, and this is the second time you tell me that! Thank you, will clarify.  As for the other two remarks: (1) upon closer reading, apparently I got it wrong (may have something to do with their original "format"?), will change (2) The "_matches with_" makes me think that it needn't be `eq`; also, they had those `**ZN**` -- presumably to label the example but i wasn't sure; will comment.  Thank you very much for comments

Comment: @zdim: I wasn't aware that I'd mentioned it before; I'm sorry to repeat myself. And the OP is particularly unclear with their requirement, making it very hard to be certain of anything, espcially when it seems that they're typing in the solutions instead of using the clipboard. Given their apparent skills I doubt that you can use *matches with* to represent anything reliable. Common parlance would use *match* for strings and *equal* for numbers.

Comment: @Borodin On the contrary -- thank you again! I apologize for not internalizing that before.  I also find some requirements unclear but hopefully they'll come back with/for clarifications. I wish I knew why exactly it isn't working for them though :(

Comment: @zdim: With the `:bsd_glob` mistakes there's no way of telling what they're actually running. Your solution works fine for me too, so it's not at your end. I've commented on the lack of precision beneath the question; let's hope it's understood.

Comment: @Borodin Of course I _copy_ and _past_ the script but it keeps giving me the same problem. That was the error that I have copied from my Terminal. I am not sure why it is a problem if this module is a core and should be installed. However I have just deleted this part with `:bsd_glob` and it works fine. @zdim Your editted script gives me blank output, I went through it in detail and everything seems to be fine, but it creates new files but prints nothing inside. It is very strange, however I have used `****` just for labelling, sorry I should have mentioned it as well

Comment: @milan  OK, let's see; let's debug it. Add printing statements in the `while` loop: after the line with `split` add `say "@fields";` and `say "@ion";`. Check out what they print. My first guess is that there is something in the data that you don't realize so that it always goes `next` and never actually gets to the line where it would print to the output file.  But you'll see when you start printing.

Comment: @zdim: Thanks. I have just made these changes that You have told me and  in terminal it prints all lines that start with `HETATM` including one with the Zn as well.. it as well creates output of new file but it is still blank.

Comment: @milan Well, what does it look like? The `$fields[3]` is compared against each term in `@ion_terms` and if it matches any then the line _is not printed_ to file.  One way to get nothing in the output file is that `$fields[3]` _always_ matches a term in `@ion_terms` ... does it?

Comment: @zdim: Thank You zdim for everyting. If You dont mind I will answer what was wrong with the script tomorrow cause I am extremely busy today and have to finish something till tomorrow. Many thanks!

Comment: @milan  By all means, take your time -- thank you for responding.  When you get to this please make sure to also read the link in my previous comment. Not only for this question but for the future as well.

Comment: @milan A tip: I know cultures where it is polite and proper to capitalize the word "you," so one respectfully writes "You" -- but this is not so in English. One never capitalizes this word in English and "You" has no particular meaning.  (People may or may not understand that you mean to be respectful.)

Comment: @zdIm: Thanks, I will read link for sure, no worries. It will be useful for the future as well. Oh really, I didn't know that. I am not for England; probably once I have seen people are using this to refer to respect as I did. Thanks! It is good to have knowledgable people so you can learn from them. Thanks! Will respond to script shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I was unclear with my advice regarding to your
previous question
[*How to delete lines that match elements from another file*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166370/how-to-delete-lines-that-match-elements-from-another-file). I suggested that you should post another question because you brought up new issues, but I intended that you should work from where we had got to, whereas you seem to have discarded all of that and started again with your original code, including shelling out to `rm` in the mistaken belief that it would delete a line from a file

Now that you have shown a full version of `ions_solvents_cofactors` I can see that my assumptions were correct, and the only other problem that you raised was that only lines starting `HETATM` should be removed from the PDB file, which you didn't say in your question

This is very similar to my previous solution, but I have added a check for `HETATM` data. I have also improved the log output so that it says which value from `ions_solvents_cofactors` was matched to cause the deletion

Please try this new code, and report if you find any problems

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';
use Tie::File;

my %matches = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'ions_solvents_cofactors';
    local $/;
    map { $_ => 1 } split ' ', <$fh>;
};

for my $pdb ( glob '*.txt' ) {

    tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $pdb or die $!;

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @file; ) {

        my ($id, undef, undef, $col4) = split ' ', $file[$i];

        if ( $id eq 'HETATM' and $col4 and $matches{$col4} ) {

            printf qq{Removing line %d from "%s" (matches %s)\n},
                    $i+1, $pdb, $col4;

            splice @file, $i, 1;
        }
        else {
            ++$i;
        }
    } 
}
```

#### output

```
Removing line 6 from "test.txt" (matches ZN)
```